# How to identify an average pricing AllocationInstruction in FIX 4.4?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to parse a FIX 4.4 AllocationInstruction (J) message, I want to identify whether an allocation is to be average priced. Unable to figure out which tag to use for that.

I've tried searching on https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/ and saw 2 tags AvgPxIndicator (field 819) and TrdType (field 828), none of these are part of FIX 4.4 AllocationInstruction.

Comment: Maybe the Allocation is average priced when either of 153/AllocAvgPx, 799/OrderAvgPx or the normal 6/AvgPx is set? Hard to say without any context but actually your trading counterparty should be able to answer this question. Some counterparties even might use one of your mentioned fields and put it on their Allocation message if they think this is a good idea. The default FIX spec is more like a guideline but every counterparty have their own rules of engagement.

Comment: Also the description of the 73/NoOrders group on the Allocation says "Indicates number of orders to be combined for average pricing and allocation." So this sounds like 799/OrderAvgPx might indicate this. But as said, your counterparty should know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another quote from the official FIX4.4 specification document, volume 5, page 37:

> **Post-Trade Allocation**
>
> Post trade allocations can be computed via one of two methods:
>
> 1. Using Average Price: Each AllocAccount has a single AllocAvgPx (e.g. US and European) (see examples 1- 1, 2-1, 3-1)
> 2. Using Executed Price: Combination of each AllocAccount and AllocPrice (unique LastPx) (e.g. Japan) (see examples 1-2, 2-2, 3-2)

But without asking your counterparty, this is just guesswork.

Comment: Thank you for the answer John, that's really helpful :)

Comment: You are welcome. Just keep in mind that every counterparty might handle things a little differently.